# Multi Object Upload to Amazon S3 not from directory in C#

Tags: c#, .net, upload, amazon-s3

I am aware of the TransferUtitlity class from the SDK but it would appear that only supports uploading large files from stream or multiple files via a hard disk.  Is there a way to use TransferUtility or another set of the AWSSDK functions to upload/put multiple objects (in the form of 'strings') to S3 using the built-in optimizations of the TransferUtility class?

To give an example, say I have 1000 string "contents" in an array and would like each of those to become an object in s3 with their own key.  What is the more efficient way to upload these objects as a group?

Comment: you could always turn the 'strings' into a Stream... please show some code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: there is no bug, its a question of best available approach.  Yes, I can change the strings to streams, but the TransferUtility does not support "multiple streams" from what Ive seen.  I want to avoid individual put calls if possible

Comment: to know which is the "best apporach" you need to provide a lot of more details and what makes in your case one approach better than another approach... although I am not sure that this is a question for SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further researching this issue and playing around with a variety of approaches, the quickest way to upload a bunch of (non huge) files to s3 was to use the TPL and parallel.foreach for each of the files to be uploaded.  This resulted in the quickest upload time.